# Is there a community here for IoT?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I think there should be a separate community/site here on the topic of [Internet of Things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_Things) (IoT).

Answer (score 6):

There is an [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site now. (See its former Area51 [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94224/internet-of-things) and definition in [this thread](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22902/define-internet-of-things)).

Stack Overflow has an active [IoT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iot) tag, with currently 894 questions.